# Logarithmic color scale in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to visualize the data with some outliers using `Plotly` and `Python3`. Outliers cause the color scale legend to look badly: there are only few high data points, but the legend looks bad: space between 2k and 10k is too big.

So the question is, how to change the appearance of 'color legend' on the right (see image below), so it will show the difference between 0 to 2k mostly? Unfortunately, couldn't get an answer from [this](https://plot.ly/python/logarithmic-color-scale/) doc file

Sample code (jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

x = np.random.randn(100,1) + 3
y = np.random.randn(100,1) + 10
x = np.reshape(x, 100)
y = np.reshape(y, 100)

color = np.random.randint(0,1000, [100])
color[[1,3,5]] = color[[1,3,5]] + 10000 # create outliers in color var

trace = Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker=dict(
        color = color,
        showscale=True,
        colorscale = [[0, 'rgb(166,206,227, 0.5)'],
                      [0.05, 'rgb(31,120,180,0.5)'],
                      [0.1, 'rgb(178,223,138,0.5)'],
                      [0.15, 'rgb(51,160,44,0.5)'],
                      [0.2, 'rgb(251,154,153,0.5)'],
                      [1, 'rgb(227,26,28,0.5)']
                     ]
    )
)

fig = Figure(data=[trace])
iplot(fig)
```

[image: Plot]

What i'm looking for:

[image: Legend]

Comment: I find the question unclear. Do you need to cut somehow the colorbar between 2k and 10k?

Comment: I'd like to stretch the distance between 0 and 2k, so it is easier to see the difference there, and that would shorten the distance between 2k and 10k, as it doesn't really show anything helpful in my case

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this can be done in plotly. Put your question in my favourites as I'm interested too. Thanks for asking

Comment: Stretching the [0,2K] in the legend only is not possible AFAIK. I think what you need instead is a log transformation of your data, not just the legend. You say the legend is useless, but the truth is even the plot is not easily read, all we can see is that a bunch of points is "around" 10.

Comment: I guess I could've come up with a better example. Even if you remove the 'outliers' by x and y and just leave the color 'outlying' - the problem with the legend persists. I'll update the example in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish what I think you're after by customizing the `colorscale`, `cmin`, and `cmax` properties to have a discrete color change at exactly 2000.  Then you can customize `colorbar.tickvals` to label the boundary as 2000.  See https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

x = np.random.randn(100,1) + 3
y = np.random.randn(100,1) + 10
x = np.reshape(x, 100)
y = np.reshape(y, 100)

color = np.random.randint(0,1000, [100])
color[[1,3,5]] = color[[1,3,5]] + 10000 # create outliers in color var

bar_max = 2000
factor = 0.9  # Normalized location where continuous colorscale should end

trace = Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker=dict(
        color = color,
        showscale=True,
        cmin=0,
        cmax= bar_max/factor,
        colorscale = [[0, 'rgb(166,206,227, 0.5)'],
                      [0.05, 'rgb(31,120,180,0.5)'],
                      [0.2, 'rgb(178,223,138,0.5)'],
                      [0.5, 'rgb(51,160,44,0.5)'],
                      [factor, 'rgb(251,154,153,0.5)'],
                      [factor, 'rgb(227,26,28,0.5)'],
                      [1, 'rgb(227,26,28,0.5)']
                     ],
        colorbar=dict(
            tickvals = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000],
            ticks='outside'
        )
    )
)

fig = Figure(data=[trace])
iplot(fig)
```

[image: New figure result]
<sup>**New figure result**</sup>

Comment: accepting as the best answere so far

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked with a precise question, I try to reply with a precise answer, even if I don't think this could not be the best in data visualization. Later I show you why.

Anyway, you can normalize the values of the colors and "squeeze" your data in a much smaller interval. It mathematically represents the power to which the number *e* must be raised to produce the original value. You can use log10 if you're more comfortable with.

The code is very very simple, I attach only the trace definition as the rest is unchanged. I placed a standard cmap for convenience as the interval of the values is continuous.

```
trace = Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker=dict(
        color = np.log(color),
        showscale=True,
        colorscale = 'RdBu'
    )
)
```

[image]

As I said, transforming the values with log isn't always the best. It actually forces the observer to a rough reading of the graph. As example, nevertheless in my example the orange markers range between 410 and 950, can you tell the difference?

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to do. I was talking about something closer to this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/zvvVr10) (my editing skills are not great :p)