# Is there a way to make a logarithmic colorbar for a 3d cone plot in Plotly?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I'm trying to visualize a vector field using the 3d cone plot in Plotly. For this purpose I need a logarithmic colorbar. This seems to be impossible without a clever workaround.

This is how my 3d plot looks like at the moment:
[image: Image of my 3d cone plot with overlapping ticks]

I was looking for a workaround but I only found solutions for heatmaps, like in these examples:

[Logarithmic color scale in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392372/logarithmic-color-scale-in-plotly)

https://github.com/plotly/documentation/issues/1611

For the heatmaps it is possible to just apply the logarithm to the z-data and then plot it using custom tick-labels for the colorbar.

As far as I know there is no way to let plotly use the logarithm of the norm of the vectors as the reference for the colorbar for a 3d cone plot.

If someone is interested, this is the code I'm using

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from emknot import *

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
z = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)


cones = []

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        for k in z: 
            print(i)
            u = [globule([i, j, k], k=1)[0]]
            v = [globule([i, j, k], k=1)[1]]
            w = [globule([i, j, k], k=1)[2]]

            cones.append(go.Cone(
            x=[i],
            y=[j],
            z=[k],
            u=u,
            v=v,
            w=w,
            cmin=0,
            cmax=1.5,
            colorbar=dict(tick0= 0, tickmode= 'array', tickvals= [0, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1,1]),
            colorscale=[[0,'rgba(255,255,255, 0.4)'],[1,'rgba(0,0,255, 1)']],
            sizemode="absolute",
            sizeref=0.6,
            anchor="center")) 


camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
    center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
    eye=dict(x=1.3, y=1.0, z=0.8)
)

layout = go.Layout(title='EM-globule')
fig = go.Figure(data=cones, layout=layout)

fig.update_layout(scene_camera=camera)
fig.write_image("images/fig1.svg")
fig.show()
```

If someone wants to reproduce my image, you need my emknot-code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jv
from scipy.integrate import quad

def phi(x):
    return np.arctan2(x[1], x[0])

def rho(x):
    return np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2)

def f(x, k):
    result = quad(lambda t: np.sin(t) * np.cos(k * x[2] * np.cos(t)) * jv(1, k * rho(x) * np.sin(t)), 0, np.pi)    
    return result[0]

def g(x,k):
    result = quad(lambda t: np.sin(t) * np.cos(t) * np.sin(k * x[2] * np.cos(t)) * jv(1, k * rho(x) * np.sin(t)), 0, np.pi)
    result = (-1) * result[0]
    return result

def h(x,k):
    result = quad(lambda t: np.sin(t) ** 2 * np.cos(k * x[2] * np.cos(t)) * jv(0, k * rho(x) * np.sin(t)), 0, np.pi)
    result = (-1) * result[0]
    return result

def ring(x, k=2*np.pi, b0=1):
    return [-b0 * f(x,k) * np.sin(phi(x)), b0 * f(x,k) * np.cos(phi(x)), 0] 

def globule(x, k=2*np.pi, b0=1):
    e_rho = np.array([np.cos(phi(x)), np.sin(phi(x)),0])
    e_z = np.array([0,0,1])
    result = b0 * g(x, k) * e_rho + h(x, k) * e_z

    return result
```

### Possible solution approach

I tried to talk to chatGPT about this issue. The code it produced is partly garbage BUT it suggested a workaround that I have not yet been able to successfully pursue:

I could create a second plot which would take the logarithm of the norm of the vectors and use its colorbar as the colorbar for the 3d cone plot. But I wasn't able to pull this off yet.

Comment: What is `emknot`? We can't reproduce the problem without it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Tranbi Sorry. I posted the code so you can reproduce it now. You could also use any arbitrary numbers that vary over several orders of magnitude for u, v, w. My problem is that I want a logarithmic colorbar so that the tick labels don't overlap.